# Android - Loop Through strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, loops

I was wondering if there is anyway to loop through the `strings.xml` file.

Let's say that I have the following format:

```xml
<!-- FIRST SECTION -->
<string name="change_password">Change Password</string>
<string name="change_server">Change URL</string>
<string name="default_password">password</string>
<string name="default_server">http://xxx:8080</string>
<string name="default_username">testPhoneAccount</string>

<!-- SECOND SECTION -->
<string name="debug_settings_category">Debug Settings</string>
<string name="reload_data_every_startup_pref">reload_data_every_startup</string>
<string name="reload_data_on_first_startup_pref">reload_data_on_first_startup</string>
```

Now let's say I have this:

```java
private HashMap<String,Integer> hashmapStringValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Is there a way to iterate only in the second section of my xml file? Maybe wrap the section with a tag like `<section2>` and then iterate through it?

```java
public void initHashMap(){
    for (int i=0;i< ???? ;i++) //Here I need to loop only in the second section of my xml file
    {          
        String nameOfTag = ? // Here I get the name of the tag
        int value = R.string.nameOfTag // Here I get the associated value of the tag

        this.hashmapStringValues.put(nameOfTag,value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what for ? ... use arrays for that ... or plain xml for settings ...

Comment: Cause I need to pass each value in a javascript document, and each value has an id in my HTML Form who corresponds to the name tag, so I can't use something like this : `<string-array name="my_keys">
    <item>Key 1</item>
    <item>Key 2</item>
    <item>Key 3</item>
    <item>Key 4</item>
    <item>Key 5</item>
    <item>Key 6</item>
</string-array>`

Comment: for one thing, if you put any xml in a folder other than raw folder, the data will not remain as an xml. aapt will generate a compressed more optimized blob which you cannot parse like an xml

Comment: `<item>key|value</item>` ... create xml with setting(put it to assets) and use `AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(...)` and parse it ...

Answer (score 6):

No, but you can create another xml file in resources/values which contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="array">
        <item>ID_1|Asdf</item>
        <item>ID_2|I do not like to think</item>
        <item>ID_3|Whatever</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

You can format your strings however you like, and then parse them with a custom parser.

To get the string array you only need to do this:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look inside your generated android.R java file, it gives you a good idea how to accomplish this via Reflection:

```
    Field fields[] = R.string.class.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Log.d("appname", field.getName() + ":" + getResources().getIdentifier(field.getName(), "string", this.getPackageName()));
    }
```

Note, I wouldn't do this often, but once for App load should be fine.

Comment: Very helpful : `R.string.class.getFields()` , **thank you!**

Comment: No problem, it makes me happy that at one point in my life I was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as basic java itself does'nt detect the comments

You can only select the string like this.

```
getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
// one way to iterate over the arrays in the strings.xml file
// is to name them all here......
String[] categories = {"millis","size_uk","size_us","size_jp"};
ArrayList<Spinner> spinners = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // iterate over the views in the layout and find the spinners
    // need to iterate over spinners separately
    // because need to identify them individually
    // in order to set their selection in the event handlers
    // of the other spinners
    GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.GridLayout1);
    for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        // if the view is a spinner.....
        if (view instanceof Spinner){
            spinners.add((Spinner)view);
        }
    }
    // it is an array of arrays
    // iterate over the arrays and fill each spinner
    // they used to be called strange objects
    // plus attach an event to each spinner
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
        Spinner spinner = spinners.get(i);
        // identify the array from it's name in the resource file
        int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(categories[i], "array",
                this.getPackageName());
        // create an adapter from said array
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, id,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //put the contents of the array in the spinner
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        //set listener event for each spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // set all spinners to the same index
                for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                    spinners.get(k).setSelection(position);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}