# How to loop thru R.string.<name>

Tags: android

I am trying to loop thru following items in strings. But getting invalid int error. What is the best solution or workaround?

```
<string name="hero_1">Akshay</string>
<string name="hero_1_number_of_movies">15</string>
<string name="hero_1_children">2</string>

<string name="hero_2">Ajay</string>
<string name="hero_2_number_of_movies">55</string>
<string name="hero_2_children">2</string>
```

Here is my java class loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<numberOfchalisas;i++) {
    int heroName = Integer.valueOf("R.string.hero_" + (i + 1));
    int numMoviesDone = Integer.valueOf("hero_"+(i+1)+"_number_of_movies");
    int numChildren = Integer.valueOf("hero_"+(i+1)+"_children");

    String name = getString(heroName);
}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/12193036/8298763

Comment: Yes seen this. string-array won't my problem. Each chunk is a String array. Thanks for your reply. @Hugosama

Comment: What you are doing is absolutely wrong. R.string.hero_1 is different than "R.string.hero_1". Former is referring to find resources in string resources having name as hero_1 which will return type of int. While latter is just a String object. You can't get same int return if you get its int value. Actually you will be thrown exception if String object don't have only Integer characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work! Try

```
for (int i=1;i<=numberOfchalisas;i++) {
    Integer heronameid = getResources().getIdentifier("hero_" + i, "string", getPackageName());
    Integer numMoviesDoneid = getResources().getIdentifier("hero_" + i +"_number_of_movies", "string", getPackageName());
    Integer numChildrenid = getResources().getIdentifier("hero_" + i +"_children", "string", getPackageName());

    String heroname = getString(heronameid);
    String numMoviesDone = getString(numMoviesDoneid);
    String numChildren = getString(numChildrenid);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer @kishan Boghra.